# Qt::DirectConnection Qt::QueuedConnection works, Qt::AutoConnection not working

Tags: c++, qt

slot `handleResults` is not called if I use `Qt::AutoConnection`

slot `handleResults` get called if I use `Qt::DirectConnection`

slot `handleResults` get called if I use `Qt::QueuedConnection`

Should I call `qRegisterMetaType`?
Why the slot get called even if I didnot call  `qRegisterMetaType`?

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork(const QString& parameter) 
    {
        QString result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        while (shouldDo)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                {

                }
            }
            std::vector<int> a{ 1,2,3 };
            emit resultReady(a);
        }
        qDebug() << "exit doWork";
    }
public:
    std::atomic<int> shouldDo = 1;
signals:
    void resultReady(std::vector<int>);
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker* worker;
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() 
    {
        worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        //connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        //connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults,Qt::DirectConnection);//works
        //connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults,Qt::QueuedConnection);//works
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults,Qt::AutoConnection);//not working
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
public slots:
    void handleResults(std::vector<int> a)
    {
        qDebug() << "handleresults="<<a;
    }
signals:
    void operate(const QString&);
};

int main6(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Controller c;

    QWidget w;
    QHBoxLayout layout;
    QPushButton pbrun("run"), pbstop("stop");
    layout.addWidget(&pbrun);
    layout.addWidget(&pbstop);
    w.setLayout(&layout);
    w.show();

    QObject::connect(&pbrun, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
        c.worker->shouldDo = 1;
        c.workerThread.start();
        emit c.operate("");
    });

    QObject::connect(&pbstop, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
        c.worker->shouldDo = 0;
    });
    return a.exec();
}

#include"FileName.moc"
```

Comment: I click stackoverflow recommended tags

Comment: As you already found out you have to register `std::vector<int>` to the Qt meta system otherwise this data type can not be queued (and this is the answer why it works with Qt::DirectConnection).

Comment: it works with both DirectConnection and QueuedConnection  @chehrlic

Comment: If it works with Qt::QueuedConnection then it also works with Qt::AutoConnection (and does so here) since Qt::AutoConnection will evaluate to Qt::QueuedConnection in your testcase.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the observed behaviour. However, you shouldn't rely on `Qt::QueuedConnection` without registering the arguments types using `qRegisterMetaType`. Even if it works now, it may fail with new Qt versions.

The difference between `Qt::QueuedConnection` and `Qt::AutoConnection` is due to a difference in the moment the arguments types are determined:

- `Qt::QueuedConnection`: arguments types are determined immediately. Qt uses template programming to support this unregistered argument type.
- `Qt::AutoConnection`: arguments types are determined during first emit that needs a queued connection. Argument types are looked up based on a text representation of the argument types.